# How to update/refresh an Apple Watch Interface Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm looking for a way to update/refresh the Interface Controller in watchkit.

Many iPhone apps employ a 'pull to refresh' or sometimes a way to reload the whole screen in a time bound manner. I'm looking for something similar for Apple Watch, but can't find an appropriate function.

(A hack will do. Preferably in swift.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a timer with a known interval to re-set the data in labels or other controls. For example, add the following code in the timer code:

Swift

```
text1.setText([DATA])
```

Objective-C

```
[text1 setText:[DATA]];
```

**NOTE:** Waiting for the new versions is always the best way. WWDC 2015 (June 8-12) will announce the new versions of WatchKit in San Francisco. They will introduce the ability of making native watch apps, and the missing APIs from WatchKit.

Comment: Thanks that's close to what I asked. I tried another approach too - scheduling a Notification and updating stuff when the notif triggers. Was looking for something more straightforward. Wish they provide something new this week in WWDC.

Comment: @NitinNain, WWDC took its place in San Francisco, and unfortunately we didn't here anything about this problem. You should do one of these ways: setText or Notification scheduling.